# the induced homomorphism between fundemental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose $X,Y$ are topological spaces, $i:X\to Y$ is the inclusion map,$i$ induces a homomorphism $i_{*}:\pi_1(X,x_0)\to \pi_1(Y,x_0)$ such that $i_{*}([f])=[i\circ f]$.

According to the definition ,we have $i_{*}([f])=[i\circ f].$ Since $i$ is the inclusion map,we have $i\circ f(t)=f(t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$,then we have $i_{*}([f])=[i\circ f]=[f]$.We can conclude that $i_{*}$ is injective without the condition that $Y$ retracts to $X$ .

Can anyone points out the wrong place.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that, even if two classes $[f]$ and $[g]$ are different in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ (that is, $f$ and $g$ are not homotopic in $X$), it can be the case that $[f]=[g]$ in $\pi_1(Y,x_0)$ (when $f$ and $g$ are homotopic in $Y$).

Indeed, when you write "$i_*([f])=[f]$" (which is true!), the "$[f]$" on the left side is different from the "$[f]$" on the right side, even if you write them with the same symbol: the one on the left side is the class of the loops (on $x_0$) homotopic (relatively to $x_0$) to $f$ in $X$, while the one on the right side is the class of the loops homotopic to $f$ in $Y$.

For instance, consider the inclusion $i$ of $D\setminus \{p\}$ into $D$, being $D$ a disk and $p$ one of its points. Let $f$ be a loop on a fixed $x_0 \in D\setminus \{p\}$ such that $f$ goes around $p$. Then clearly $[f]\neq[\sigma_{x_0}]$ in $\pi_1(D\setminus \{p\})$, but of course $[f]=[\sigma_{x_0}]$ in $\pi_1(D)$. Here $\sigma_{x_0}$ denotes the constant loop on $x_0$. Hence in this case $i_*$ is not injective. And indeed $D\setminus \{p\}$ is not a retract of $D$!

Edit. I rewrite everything with the clarifying notation.

The point is that, even if two classes $[f]_X$ and $[g]_X$ are different in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ (that is, $f$ and $g$ are not homotopic in $X$), it can be the case that $[f]_Y=[g]_Y$ in $\pi_1(Y,x_0)$ (when $f$ and $g$ are homotopic in $Y$).

Indeed, when you write "$i_*([f]_X)=[f]_Y$" (which is true!), the "$[f]_X$" on the left side is different from the "$[f]_Y$" on the right side: $[f]_X$ the one on the left side is the class of the loops (on $x_0$) homotopic (relatively to $x_0$) to $f$ in $X$, while $[f]_Y$ is the class of the loops homotopic to $f$ in $Y$.

For instance, consider the inclusion $i$ of $D\setminus \{p\}$ into $D$, being $D$ a disk and $p$ one of its points. Let $f$ be a loop on a fixed $x_0 \in D\setminus \{p\}$ such that $f$ goes around $p$. Then clearly $[f]_{D\setminus\{p\}}\neq[\sigma_{x_0}]_{D\setminus\{p\}}$ in $\pi_1(D\setminus \{p\})$, but of course $[f]_D=[\sigma_{x_0}]_D$ in $\pi_1(D)$. Here $\sigma_{x_0}$ denotes the constant loop on $x_0$. Hence in this case $i_*$ is not injective. And indeed $D\setminus \{p\}$ is not a retract of $D$!

Comment: You mean $i\circ f$ is not homotopic to $f$?But according to the definition,it does.

Comment: I mean that $i \circ f$ here should be seen as a loop in $Y$, while $f$ is a loop in $X$, so they represent elements of diffent groups: $[i \circ f] \in \pi_1(Y,x_0)$ and $[f] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$. In order to understan this, I suggest you to use two different notations: denote with $[\cdot]_X$ the elements of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and with $[\cdot]_Y$ the elements of $\pi_1(Y,x_0)$. Then your equation becomes: $i_*([f]_X)=[ i \circ f]_Y=[ f ]_Y$. Does it make more sense? What I was trying to explain is that $[f]_X$ and $[ f ]_Y$ represent two different things.

Comment: And hence the equation $i_*([f]_X)=[ f ]_Y$ is not enough to conclude the injectivity.

Comment: In my example indeed (using the clarifying notation), even if $[f]_{D\setminus \{p\}}\neq [\sigma_{x_0}]_{D\setminus \{p\}}$, it is the case that $[f]_{D}= [\sigma_{x_0}]_{D}$

Comment: If $f$ is a loop in $X$ with base point $x_0$ in $X$ and $X\subset Y$,should $i\circ f=f$ be a loop in $Y$?Th loop doesn't change?

Comment: Yes, I mean... $f$ is also a loop in $X$ but this is not the point. The main point is that, when you regard it as a loop in $X$ then it represents $[f]_X \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$, and when you regard it as a loop in $Y$ then it represents $[f]_Y \in \pi_1(Y,y_0)$. And $[f]_X$ and $[f]_Y$ are two different things.

Comment: Can I understand like this:there is a possibilty that $g\in [f]_Y$ but $g$ is not in $[f]_X$?

Comment: Yes, precisely!!

Comment: And indeed what you wrote is equivalent to: there is a possibility that $[g]_Y=[f_Y]$ but $[g]_X\neq [f]_X$. In this case $i_*$ is not injective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99397/discussion-between-gennaro-pasquale-and-math112358).

Comment: I see it,thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You're very welcome!